# mod_rewrite positioning and wording

Tags: mod-rewrite

I renamed about 50 pages of my website.  I want to make an internal rewrite from the old pages to the new pages. This is the example that Apache gives.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteRule    ^foo\.html$  bar.html
```

I am not sure if I need the `rewriteBase /`.  I have only individual webpages (no subs).
I understand the terms "foo" and "bar" and "quux" are universal words for examples. If I have only one domain on this server, and the rewrite rule will apply to the root directory, do I need to include `rewriteBase /`, `rewriteBase /~quux/`, or do I even need `rewriteBase`?

I assume that when using `rewriteBase /~quux/`, the actual subdirectory is inserted were `/~quux/` is. Even though I don't have subdirectories, is this correct?

Can someone please arrange the correct script illustrated above?

Also, I understand that this script would be placed BEFORE other .htaccess directives, such as non-www to www and index to /. Is this correct?

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

#rewrite old to new pages internaly
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteRule    ^foo\.html$  bar.html

#non-www to www
RewriteCond
RewriteRule ...

#index to /
RewriteCond
RewriteRule ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**RewriteBase:**

If your page is like:

```
http://mydomain.com/subdir/index.html
```

and your .htaccess file is in `subdir/`, then you need to set it:

```
RewriteBase /subdir/
```

This lets you make your rules ignore the subdirectory, so

```
RewriteRule ^old_index.html$ new_index.html
```

would redirect `subdir/old_index.html` to `subdir/new_index.html`

**Positioning:**

The positioning of the rules only matter if you are not using the `[L]` flag after your rules. This modifier tells mod_rewrite to stop rewriting and make the redirect. Not using it will let the rewrite engine do everything it can with your url in one go. So if your url is like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/old_index.html
```

It will be converted to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/new_index.html
```

No matter which rule comes first, the one that adds the www. or the one that points to the new pages. But if there is an `[L]` flag, then it may be done in 2 redirects.